# Differentiable function: proof of inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m} $, $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \;$, $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \; ,a<b $ and $f,g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ also $f,g$ are differentiable functions on $(a,b)$ and $\forall t \in (a,b):|f'(t)|\leq g'(t)$. Set some $\epsilon >0$
Let's take some point $m \in (a,b)$ which function f and g are differentiable in. Let's take some $\delta > 0 $ such that : $\delta < b - m $ and such that $\forall t \in (m,m+\delta):|\frac{g(t)-g(m)}{t-m}-g'(m)|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Why can we write $g'(m)\leq \frac{g(t)-g(m)}{t-m} +\frac{\epsilon}{2} $ with the previous inequality ?

Comment: Because for any real numbers, $|a-b| < c$ is equivalent to: $a-b<c$ *or* $-c < a-b$. The second inequality is equivalent to $b < a+c$. Hence, $|a-b| < c$ implies $b < a+c$.

Comment: oh okay XD, thank  You

Comment: no you are wrong |a−b|<c is equivalent to: a−b<c and −c<a−b

Comment: but operator should be and not or

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. I cannot edit the comment any more, but the implication is correct nonetheless. $|a-b|>c$ would give rise to an "or", I got them mixed up.

Comment: why is that so ?